# Creating node webkit installable

Tags: angularjs, node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

I am developing a Windows application using node webkit for serial USB connection.

When I run the script using node command it gives me exact output:

```
var usb = require('usb');

var devices = usb.getDeviceList();

console.log("Devices are="+devices.length);

var findDevice=usb.findByIds(1027,24577);

console.log("Devices found="+findDevice);

findDevice.open();
```

When I implement it with HTML pages however, it gives me the error

> invalid access to memory location while accessing USB using command `require('usb')` of script

The code snippet I tried is

```
$scope.callFun=function()
{
    var usb=require('usb');

    var devices = usb.getDeviceList();
}
```

I have already installed `node-pre-gyp` and `npm install usb`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, not sure but it might just work.

Add a ['node-main'](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/node-main) script, and in there have do the require in the following manner:

```
exports.usb = require('usb');
```

Then, in your html use `exports.usb` to access it:

```
var devices = exports.usb.getDeviceList();
```

It really is a shot in the dark but it helped me when I had a similar issue. Did it work?